Query over 30-day increments in Postgresql
I have two queries.  One that returns a count of records over the last 30 days, and another for the 30 days prior.  I'd like to combine them into one query.
SELECT
cat.title as category, count(*) as total_count
FROM history h
JOIN users u on h.user_id = u.id
JOIN training t on t.id = h.app_id
JOIN training_categories tc on tc.training_id = t.id
JOIN category cat on cat.id = tc.category_id
WHERE u.department_id = 1 and h.type = 'virtual'
and h.app = 'training' and h.status = 'active'
and cat.status = 'active' and h.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')
GROUP BY cat.title
ORDER BY total_count DESC

SELECT
cat.title as category, count(*) as total_count
FROM history h
JOIN users u on h.user_id = u.id
JOIN training t on t.id = h.app_id
JOIN training_categories tc on tc.training_id = t.id
JOIN category cat on cat.id = tc.category_id
WHERE u.department_id = 1 and h.type = 'virtual'
and h.app = 'training' and h.status = 'active'
and cat.status = 'active' and h.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days') and h.created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')
GROUP BY cat.title
ORDER BY total_count DESC

In my attempts to solve this so far it looks like I need a window function, but where I'm stuck is how to partition the query by 30-day increments.

Easiest - use conditional aggregation with filter clause.
SELECT
  cat.title as category, 
  count(*) filter
   (where h.created_at between now()-interval '30 days' 
                           and now()) total_00_30,
  count(*) filter 
   (where h.created_at between now()-interval '60 days'
                           and now()-interval '31 days') total_31_60
FROM ...
-- <part of your query here>
  and h.created_at >= (now()- interval '60 days') and ...
-- <part of your query here>


Looks good to me but I get all zeroes for the counts.  Edit: I reversed the order of the args to BETWEEN and it worked.

Oh, sure! My mistake. Fixed.

If the above answer resolved your issue, or lead you to the solution, then kindly accept it. This aids future users having the same or similar issue and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.
